# Refreshing Modal content with Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having issues with getting a form loaded into a modal in BS4 to repost (post to self in affect), check the form input, and re-load the modal div with the error, or re-direct to checkout page.

The initial Ajax loading of the form from select.php loads well, but upon pressing the submit button on the form within select.php in the modal, I just get no response at all from the button, as if the button it dead, nothing shown in console etc.

Any ideas at all? I'm new to using JQ and Ajax etc, but it seems quite close to what other people are doing in their code.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.view_data').click(function() {
            var eventID = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                url: "select.php",
                method: "post",
                data: {
                    eventID: eventID,
                    selectToken: 'true'
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#modal-body').html(data);
                    $('#ticketsModal').modal("show");
                }
            });
        });



        // process the form in select.php shown in the modal
        $('#ticketForm').submit(function(event) {

            // get the form data
            // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
            var formData = {
                'maleplaces': $('input[name=maleplaces]').val(),
                'femaleplaces': $('input[name=femaleplaces]').val(),
                'friendplaces': $('input[name=friendplaces]').val(),
                'eventID': $('input[name=eventID]').val(),
                'ticketSubmit': $('input[name=ticketSubmit]').val()
            };


            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST', 
                    url: 'select.php', 
                    data: formData, 
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    encode: true
                })
                // using the done promise callback

                .done(function(data) {
                    $('#modal-body').html(data);
                    console.log(data);

                    // here we will handle errors and validation messages
                });

            // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
            event.preventDefault();
        });


    });
</script>
```

The Modal code on the main.php page is here as requested:

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ticketsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Select </h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal End-->
```

Here is the form in select.php:

```
            <form id="ticketForm" name="ticketForm" method="post" action="select.php">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="maleplaces" id="maleplaces" class="custom-select">
                        <option value="0" selected>Male Tickets (0)</option>
                        <option value="1">Male Tickets (x1)</option>
                        <option value="2">Male Tickets (x2)</option>
                        <option value="3">Male Tickets (x3)</option>
                        <option value="4">Male Tickets (x4)</option>
                        <option value="5">Male Tickets (x5)</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="femaleplaces" id="femaleplaces" class="custom-select">
                        <option value="0" selected>Female Tickets (0)</option>
                        <option value="1">Female Tickets (x1)</option>
                        <option value="2">Female Tickets (x2)</option>
                        <option value="3">Female Tickets (x3)</option>
                        <option value="4">Female Tickets (x4)</option>
                        <option value="5">Female Tickets (x5)</option>
                    </select>
                </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="friendplaces" id="friendplaces" class="custom-select">
                    <option value="0" selected>Double Tickets (0)</option>
                    <option value="1">Saver Tickets (x1)</option>
                    <option value="2">Saver Tickets (x2)</option>
                    <option value="3">Saver Tickets (x3)</option>
                    <option value="4">Saver Tickets (x4)</option>
                    <option value="5">Saver Tickets (x5)</option>
                </select>

                <input name="eventID" type="hidden" id="eventID" value="<?php echo $event['event_id']; ?>" />
                <input name="ticketSubmit" type="hidden" id="ticketSubmit" value="<?php echo $event['event_id']; ?>" />

            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto my-1">
        <button type="submit" id="ticket_btn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return doubleticketFunction()">Continue to payment</button>
    </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: is this  the div `#modal-body` you show data response in ? or its modal body?

Comment: Can you add the HTML code as well?

Comment: can you try like this
            `<div id="modal-body"> </div>` I know its can you try as shown please

Comment: @GhoSTBG  - I've added the Modal code (just standard from BS4 docs)

Comment: @Dilek - #modal-body is the name and ID of the div where the response data from select.php is echoed. I've now included the modal code. Cheers.

Comment: If the `#ticketForm` doesn't exist on the page when the page is loaded, you can't (directly) attach a handler to it.  You need to use a delegated handler with [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: @PatrickQ - Thanks. I don't pretend to understand exactly how I fix it, but it makes sense and I sort of wondered if it would be something along those lines and explains why that button is dead.

Comment: @MattNoNo I dont see a submit button in your html  `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Because you dynamically change your `#ticketForm` element you lose the bind with the `submit` event listener when you replace your form. You'll have to either *rebind* the event or use [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) to listen for the events. In this example I've chosen the former to elaborate.

First take your function that you use in the `$('#ticketForm').sumbit` and name it. You'll be using this function to bind the first form and all the forms that replace it.

```
function ticketFormSubmit(event) {

  // Use jQuery serialize to get the form values.
  var formData = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'select.php', 
    data: formData, 
    dataType: 'json', 
    encode: true
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    $('#modal-body').html(data);
    console.log(data);
  });

  event.preventDefault();
}
```

In the succes callback of your `$.ajax` call select the newly added form and add the event listener to it like in the example below.

```
$('.view_data').click(function()     
  var eventID = $(this).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    method: "post",
    data: {
      eventID: eventID,
      selectToken: 'true'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#modal-body').html(data);
      $('#ticketsModal').modal("show");

      // Bind new submit event listener
      $('#ticketForm').on('submit', ticketFormSubmit);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried implementing your code but the button is still dead. I'm probably not adding it correctly but I'm a fish out of water with JQuery.

Comment: Does your new form also have the `ticketForm` id? Add the HTML of the form that you download to your question above. No worries, mate. We'll get you going.

Comment: Yes, the form via select.php which echos into the modal on main.php, has the id of ticketForm. I edited my OP with the code I 'think' you suggested to me and how to use? Again, with this code the initial load of the modal and Ajaxed content served from select.php, is perfect, still dead when I try the submit button on the form from select.php inside the modal (I've tested the form via old fashion ways and it works fine.)

Comment: It would help a lot if you add your form to your question above. The solution lies there.

Comment: hi, i've just added the form from select.php. Cheers.

Comment: `onclick="return doubleticketFunction()"` What does this do on your submit button? My guess is that line breaks JS and therefor does not execute your submit function.

Comment: thanks, I tried removing the onclick function (which just does a confirm alert) and the submit button is still dead with no sign of life in the console output. Disappointing because I feel I got so close, but will have to revert to the old fashioned way and go back to the drawing board.Thanks for the help.